Delete rows without budget and act
I've a table data

For the same ER and month, if there's no data for scenario budget_N or act_N, so no insertion in the final table:

This is what I think a good point to start
select *
FROM your_table
WHERE (ER, MONTH) IN (
    SELECT ER, MONTH
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY ER, MONTH
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN SCENARIO_CD = 'BUDGET_N' THEN 1 END) = 0
       OR COUNT(CASE WHEN SCENARIO_CD = 'ACT_N' THEN 1 END) = 0
);


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

You can't do TUPLEd IN in sql Server, but this looks like EXISTS

This fiddle might help experiment with your options https://dbfiddle.uk/n7V0flWu

@BartMcEndree, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Delete with join two tables is possible in SQL Server.
Assuming we only have two Scenario_cd, BUDGET_N and ACT_N
DELETE a
FROM you_table as a
LEFT JOIN you_table as b
  ON a.ER=b.ER
  AND a.MONTH = b.MONTH
  AND b.SCENARIO_CD = (
          CASE 
            WHEN a.SCENARIO_CD = 'BUDGET_N' THEN 'ACT_N'
            WHEN a.SCENARIO_CD = 'ACT_N' THEN 'BUDGET_N'
          END
          )
WHERE b.SCENARIO_CD is null


See examples
select er,month,scenario_cd
from(
select *
  ,lead(scenario_cd)over(partition by er order by scenario_cd) nextScenario_cd
  ,lag(scenario_cd)over(partition by er order by scenario_cd) prevScenario_cd
from your_table
)t
where scenario_cd='ACT_N' and nextScenario_cd='BUDGET_N'
  or scenario_cd='BUDGET_N' and prevScenario_cd='ACT_N'

or, IMHO better (only one table scan)
select er,month,scenario_cd
from(
select *
  ,sum(case when scenario_cd='ACT_N' then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by er ) Act_n_qty
  ,sum(case when scenario_cd='BUDGET_N' then 1 else 0 end)over(partition by er ) budget_n_qty
from your_table
)t
where Act_n_qty>0 and Budget_n_qty>0

Demo with query plan
